# Not able to execute URL with json value in JAVA API springs

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am tiring to execute some of my project URLs through JAVA APIs. But some of them contain JSON values. Its not accepting the JSON I am providing.
If I hit same URL through browser it executes. I am not getting what is going wrong. Are the " " specified not accepted ?

URL = http://admin.biin.net:8289/project.do?cmd=AddProject&mode=default&projectFieldValueJSON={"fieldIds":[{"id":1360,"value":"project SS33"},{"id":1362,"value":"12/03/2015"},{"id":1363,"value":"12/31/2015"}],"state":1}&jsessionid=AE5B03C9791D1019DCD7BBF0E34CCFEE

The Code is as follows

```
String requestString = "http://admin.biin.net:8289 /project.do?cmd=AddProject&mode=default&projectJSON={"fieldIds":[{"id":1360,"value":"project SS33"},{"id":1362,"value":"12/03/2015"},{"id":1363,"value":"12/31/2015"}],"state":1}&jsessionid=AE5B03C9791D1019DCD7BBF0E34CCFEE"
 URL url = new URL(requestString); 
 HttpURLConnection conn =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 conn.connect();

 InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

 StringBuffer responseString = new StringBuffer();
 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    responseString.append(line);
   }
```

Error :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://admin.biin.net:8289/project.do?cmd=AddProject&mode=default&projectJSON={"fieldIds":[{"id":1360,"value":"project SS33"},{"id":1362,"value":"12/03/2015"},{"id":1363,"value":"12/31/2015"}],"state":1}&jsessionid=AE5B03C9791D1019DCD7BBF0E34CCFEE
```

If I remove the JSON the URL executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass json in `QueryString`. Since you are using `HTTP POST`. You should send the sensitive data in the HTTP body. Like this

```
String str =  "some string goes here";
byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write( outputInBytes );    
os.close();
```

For your current problem. Encode the json value before passing it in url.

Try this:

```
try {
        String s = "http://admin.biin.net:8289/project.do?cmd=AddProject&mode=default&projectFieldValueJSON=" 
                    + URLEncoder.encode("{\"fieldIds\":[{\"id\":1360,\"value\":\"project SS33\"},{\"id\":1362,\"value\":\"12/03/2015\"},{\"id\":1363,\"value\":\"12/31/2015\"}],\"state\":1}", "UTF-8") 
                    + "&jsessionid=AE5B03C9791D1019DCD7BBF0E34CCFEE";
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Result: http://admin.biin.net:8289/project.do?cmd=AddProject&mode=default&projectFieldValueJSON=%7B%22fieldIds%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1360%2C%22value%22%3A%22project+SS33%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1362%2C%22value%22%3A%2212%2F03%2F2015%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1363%2C%22value%22%3A%2212%2F31%2F2015%22%7D%5D%2C%22state%22%3A1%7D&jsessionid=AE5B03C9791D1019DCD7BBF0E34CCFEE
```